# Should one combine setState statements when possible?

Tags: reactjs

Trying to optimize my React app… should one combine `setState` statements when possible or it is best practice to keep them separate?

```js
setLength(10)
setLengthPercentage(10)
setMarks(["foo", "bar"])
```

vs

```js
setAll({
  length: 10,
  lengthPercentage: 10,
  marks: ["foo", "bar"],
})
```

Which is best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both approaches often work fine, but [React recommends](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables):

> We recommend to split state into multiple state variables based on which values tend to change together.

So if you will always call `setLength`, `setLengthPercentage`, and `setMarks` together, putting them into a single state variable makes sense. If you might update one but not all at once, it could be easier to have separate states.

Using a single object for state really shines when you have a *lot* of similar stateful values that get updated with similar logic - for example, in a form with many fields, having a single state object can reduce much of the boilerplate that'd otherwise be required.

Still, it's completely up to you, based on how you'd like the code to look. There are no hard and fast rules.

Comment: And when updating the state object becomes more complex, there's [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

Comment: My understanding is that recent versions of React batch `setState` statements under the hood. Is that accurate?

Comment: @sunknudsen In a sense - if the state setters are being called inside of React handlers (like a click handler), there will only be one re-render even if multiple state setters are called. If the state setters are called *outside* a React handler, such as in a `.then` or `setTimeout`, the re-render will occur immediately for each state setter (because React doesn't know when the browser will yield control back to it). Still, almost never worth worrying about in either case